# How to detect laptop as DeviceType from DeviceFamily in UWP

Tags: c#, c++, uwp

I need to find the device type either Desktop or laptop by using DeviceFamily in UWP. But it return always Desktop even if i run my application with laptop.How to get laptop instead of return Desktop? is there any specific method or WINAPI available for this?Please suggest.

Comment: You could maybe check if a touchpad is available, though then a Surface with the keyboard would be a tablet as well. And you can't check if it has touch or not, cause the XPS13 e.g. is a laptop with touch support. So checking for an internal battery (if possible) would not help as well. So physically I don't think there is a way to do this by 100%.

Comment: To answer your question we must first think of what a Desktop and what a Laptop is. To a human it is easy to distinguish but from the OS perspective a Desktop and a Laptop are not so different. They are both machines running full windows 10 with similar form factors and processing capabilities. That's why the OS does not distinguish between them. There is a helper class [here](https://gist.github.com/wagonli/40d8a31bd0d6f0dd7a5d). It still won't differentiate between Desktop and Laptop, because Widnows doesn't. What is it that you are trying to achieve? Maybe we can help you in some other way.